# Transaction push over Blockchain but NOT to send it to PartyB

Tags: corda

i am using the https://github.com/corda/corda-tut2-solution-kotlin template for my simple corda app. i have modified it with some addition fields in IOU but i dont want to send to PartyB. i just want to push data over blockchain. I have modified the flows.kt and StateAndContracts.kt source files. but i am unable to do so. i still see the transactions goes to PartyB as well.

Can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As part of `FinalityFlow`, a transaction is sent to all the `participants` of all the transaction's input and output states. I assume in your case, PartyB is one of the `participants` in the output, so they receive the transaction.

Note that even if you were to remove PartyB as a participant on the output, they would still receive a copy of the full transaction because they are a participant on the input (although they would not store this output state in their vault). We are doing work with SGX (see https://docs.corda.net/head/design/sgx-integration/design.html) to make it so that PartyB would not be able to see the output state at all, even though they are a participant of the input.